# PHP read lock file created by a different Linux user?

Tags: php, linux, permissions, locking

On my Linux server, I have 2 Linux users:

- **Jim** - maintains a central framework repository that other users use, including some 3rd party open source libraries such as [Jobby](https://github.com/jobbyphp/jobby).
- **Rob** - uses the framework maintained by Jim to do specific work.

Jobby is a PHP cron management script that creates a lock file at /tmp/xxxxx.lck for each job / process that's been started.

Before **Rob** came in, **Jim** used to do all the stuff including both the central framework AND the specific work. Therefore the cron script will be run as **Jim** and the lock file will be created and owned by **Jim** thus the script reads the lock file no problem.

However, when **Rob** came in and took over the specific work, the cron script by **Rob** is run as **Rob** which calls the Jobby library owned by **Jim**. The lock file is thus created and owned by **Jim**. Now the cron script by **Rob** can't read the lock file created by **Jim** and keeps giving the Jobby error:

> ERROR: Unable to open file (File: /tmp/xxxx.lck).

Basically, script A (**Rob**) calls script B (**Jim**) which creates /tmp/xxxx.lck (-rw-r--r-- 1 Jim Jim), is there any secure way to make script A (**Rob**) able to read /tmp/xxxx.lck?

But ain't the permissions (-rw-r--r--) all right since it allows anyone to read the file? That's really odd.

Then why is Jobby giving this error?

## Update

It occurs to me when I'm writing this question that I should find out why Jobby is throwing this error in the first place. And I found this:

```
public function acquireLock($lockfile)
{
    if (array_key_exists($lockfile, $this->lockHandles)) {
        throw new Exception("Lock already acquired (Lockfile: $lockfile).");
    }

    if (!file_exists($lockfile) && !touch($lockfile)) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to create file (File: $lockfile).");
    }

    $fh = fopen($lockfile, "r+");
    if ($fh === false) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to open file (File: $lockfile).");
    }

    $attempts = 5;
    while ($attempts > 0) {
        if (flock($fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
            $this->lockHandles[$lockfile] = $fh;
            ftruncate($fh, 0);
            fwrite($fh, getmypid());
            return;
        }
        usleep(250);
        --$attempts;
    }

    throw new InfoException("Job is still locked (Lockfile: $lockfile)!");
}
```

So it is asking for both **reading and writing** permissions of the lock file.

Since the lock file is (-rw-r--r-- 1 Jim Jim) script of Rob won't be able to write to it --- I guess this is the problem?

But why does Jobby creates the file as **Jim** but opens it as **Rob**?

Is there any way I can make it both **creates** and then **opens** the file as Rob?

Answer (score 0):

This is awkward. Seems /tmp/xxxx.lck was originally created by Jim before Rob came in.

So all I need is to delete the file /tmp/xxxx.lck as Jim. Now when Rob runs his script, the same lock file will be created as Rob and everything's all right again.